# How can I draw the depth value in GLSL?

Tags: opengl, shaders, glsl

I want to draw the depth buffer in the fragment shader, I do this:

**Vertex shader:**

```
varying vec4 position_;

gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
position_ = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
```

**Fragment shader:**

```
float depth = ((position_.z / position_.w) + 1.0) * 0.5;

gl_FragColor = vec4(depth, depth, depth, 1.0);
```

But all I print is white, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you want to draw depth buffer of rendered scene or draw scene objects with coloring based on pixel depth?

Answer (score 4):

position_.z shouldn't be larger than 1 or lower than 0. You should try to use linear depth for the display, which after applying the projection matrix is (usually) stored in the w coordinate instead. Take that, divide by an appropriate number (depending on the scale of your game) to bring the numbers between 0 and 1 for your interesting depth and watch.

gl_fragcoord is not relevant to this discussion; gl_fragdepth is an output variable to modify the post-projection depth in the pixel shader. You're not trying to do that, so don't use that either.

Answer (score 2):

A cheesy way might be to set up some linear fog.  Make the fog colour black, draw all your geometry white, and voila.

Comment: Nice idea for a fixed-function pipeline, never thought about that.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try one of these two variables. [gl_fragcoord](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/xhtml/gl_FragCoord.xml) or [gl_fragdepth](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/xhtml/gl_FragDepth.xml)

I didn't read those manuals, but I think, it could be helpful.